# How to test a trained CNN model in an external non-Tensorflow environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, data-science, object-detection

I have trained a pre-trained Tensorflow model for my custom object detection and I have exported the inference graph file and the checkpoint files. Now I want somebody else also to test out my trained model, by feeding some new images to it and seeing the results. But what is the best way to do so if the external 'evaluators' don't have any Tensorflow environment and they don't want to set it up either?

I used:

Miniconda3, Tensorflow v1.10.0 (gpu), 
Tensorboard v1.10.0, 
Cudatoolkit 8.0, TF pre-trained model "SSD with Mobilenet v1".

All manuals that I have found and read, only guide you to test your model from running some code from the Tensorflow object_detection folder. But setting up a TF can be quite a hassle for somebody who hasn't done it before. I thought maybe there is a way to somehow "package it up" so others can just easily run it with as little effort as possible. For just an example, let's consider "easy" a scenario where I send them a file package with a ready made Jupyter Notebook in it, so the only effort would be to unpack it and learn how to use the notebook.

Please kindly help with suggestions, possibly different ones, with different expertise levels and different understanding of "easily". But please consider that I am also a newbie in this field.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`tfdeploy`](https://github.com/riga/tfdeploy).

It is a lightweight package that allows you to deploy your tensorflow models as a callable object using `numpy` (which is a way more reasonable dependency to have).

Answer (score 1):

[TensorFlow Serving](https://medium.com/tensorflow/serving-ml-quickly-with-tensorflow-serving-and-docker-7df7094aa008) maybe an overkill here (as it requires Docker), but it provides the inference environment via REST API.